# How to write partial derivatives in Mathcad

Tags: mathcad

I am using Mathcad 14 and I would like to know if one can write partial derivatives in Mathcad. On the Calculus palette we just have the normal derivative symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Mathcad 15---

I can insert a derivative using the `Calculus` palette, and then right-click
on the derivative. Choose `View Derivative As > Partial Derivative` on the popup menu.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. This works with Mathcad 14 as well. I will give you 1 vote up when my reputation score gets above 15!

Comment: But in Mathcad 14 on reopening the file, the normal derivative appears again even if the file was last saved with the derivative as a partial one. A bug in Mathcad 14.